pandas read_excel gets extra precision digits for float number
I am writing a piece of code to validate the digit precision of an excel file, and I got extra digits when read to pandas dataframe. This is the data in the file, which is 116.96 with two digits precision. There's no tricky in the  formula bar.

when I use df=pd.read_excel(file, na_values="", keep_default_na=False, thousands=','), the value of this line becomes 116.96000000000001. Since I am validating it, I cannot round digit by code. I have to read the original one from file. What's possible reason here?
